# List the file with 12* and 13* series at one shot

Tags: shell-script, shell

Hi I have the list of file starting with series like ABC1*, ABC12* and ABC13* ABC14* series...

I want to get the list of ABC12* and ABC13* with find command

I am using the below command but not able to extract exact results..

```
ls -ltr |grep -e "ABC12" |find . -type f -mtime 15
```

Comment: try `find . -type f -mtime 15 -name 'ABC1[23]*'`

Answer (score 0):

Note that `-mtime 15` means *"whose age rounded up to the next 24-hour unit is 15"*, that is files modified between `14*24` hours ago and `15*24` hours ago (note that we're not talking of *days* here as in many timezones, you have one 23 hour day and one 25 hour day per year). Assuming that's what you want, with `zsh`, you could do:

```
ls -lrtd -- **/ABC1[23](D.m15)
```

Or:

```
find . -type f -name 'ABC1[23]' -mtime 15 -exec ls -lrtd {} +
```

However note that if the number of files exceeds the maximum size of the arguments and environment passed to a command, the first one will fail while the second one will cause several instances of `ls` to be run and thus the list not be in time order as requested with `-t`.

With `zsh` and GNU `ls`, you can work around that with:

```
autoload zargs
zargs -- **/ABC1[23](D.m15Om) -- ls -lUd
```

That is, let `zsh` do the sorting and pass the list to one or more `ls` invocations as necessary but telling `ls` not to sort the list. For other `ls` implementations, you can replace the `U` with `rt` to let it do another useless but harmless sorting.

If you wanted a range like `ABC17` -> `ABC23` instead of just `ABC12`, `ABC13`, with `zsh`, you'd do:

```
ls -lrtd -- **/ABC<17-23>(D.m15)
```

(note however that `ABC<17-23>` matches `ABC17` but also `ABC0000017`. If that's an issue change `<17-23>` to `(<17-23>~^??)` (`extendedglob` option needed for the `pattern~exclude` glob operator though) to ensure it only matches on 2 digit numbers or `(<17-23>~0*)` to exclude numbers with leading 0).

If it's file whose name *starts* with `ABC12` as opposed to *is* `ABC12`, then you'd do

```
ls -lrtd -- **/ABC<17-23>*(D.m15)
```

But then note that that would also match on ABC170. To avoid that:

```
setopt extendedglob
ls -lrtd -- **/ABC<17-23>^[0-9]*(D.m15)
```

That is, `<17-23>` followed by anything but something that starts with a decimal digit.

The `find` equivalent (though not allowing leading zeros and with the problem above for large numbers of files, and with potential problems if file names contain invalid characters, and with a `./` prefix on all files) would be sometime like:

```
find . \( -name 'ABC1[7-9]*' -o -name 'ABC2[0-3]*' \) \
       ! -name 'ABC??[0-9]*' -mtime 15 -type f \
      -exec ls -lrtd {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

`-name` option search for the pattern. Square brackets mean OR for what is inside.

```
find . -type f -name  'ABC1[23]*'
```

Comment: Note that it matches on `ABC128`